# For loop using Angular service, wait until finished before going to next page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I am calling a service using a "for" loop and want to wait until I'm finished before going to the next page (route), so the data is all there before it loads and I'm not sure how to do it.

Here are my services:

```
.service("OrdersService", function($http, $rootScope, $location) {
   var getData = {};

    getData.eachOrder = function(id){
        var url = '/service/rest/orders';

        return $http.get(url+'/'+id)                    

        .success(function(data) {
            getData.allOrders(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.error('Error fetching feed:', status, headers, config);
        });
    };

    getData.allOrders = function(data){
        $rootScope.ordersTotal = $rootScope.ordersTotal || [];
        $rootScope.ordersTotal.push(data);
    };
});
```

And here is my for loop

```
$scope.viewDetails = function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.checkedIds.length; i++){
        if($scope.checkedIds[i]){                                                          
            OrdersService.eachOrder(i);                                                                                                              
        }
    }  

    // here's where I'd like to wait until loop finished before changing location
    $location.path('/details');  
};
```

(**checkedIds** contains and array or numbers.)

Thanks for any help. I'm fairly new to Angular, so I'm happy to take any tips on how this code could be done better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OrderService.eachOrder` returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), so you can wait for them all to finish using `$q.all`:

```
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.checkedIds.length; i++){
    if($scope.checkedIds[i]){                                                          
        promises.push(OrdersService.eachOrder(i));
    }
}  

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    $location.path('/details');  
});
```